# Echo value from a cell if cells are equal (Excel)

Tags: excel

So I have 2 sheets in excel, one with loads of data I need to "echo" (sorry more familiar with SQL/PHP) out the value of a cell, if 2 cells agree.

For example, in one sheet I have 2 columns, "old" & "new" which reference sku's as the manufacturer has updated all their codes. I need to echo the old code in a separate sheet where the new codes are equal.

So in sheet 2 I have for example "name", "new sku", "description" etc. I've added a column called "old sku" and now need to check the other sheet for instances where the new sku's match and return the old sku.

I've tried referencing other fields using Old_vs_New_Codes!A2 etc but I'm not entirely sure how to do the comparison/return. The old vs new codes sheet contains thousands of codes, and my "main" worksheet maybe hundreds, so I need to check for matches and return.

New table structure "Sheet1":

| Old code | New code | Description | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| formula? | 56789 | Product 1 | £200 |
| formula? | 10111 | Product 2 | £150 |
| formula? | 21314 | Product 3 | £99 |

Reference worksheet "Sheet2":

| Old code | New code |
| --- | --- |
| abcde | 56789 |
| fghij | 35462 |
| klmno | 10111 |
| pqrst | 43433 |
| uvwxy | 21314 |

Expected result in "Sheet1":

| Old code | New code | Description | Cost |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abcde | 56789 | Product 1 | £200 |
| klmno | 10111 | Product 2 | £150 |
| uvwxy | 21314 | Product 3 | £99 |

Comment: match() or an if() should work. Show some clear example data and you might get some example formulae to work with.

Comment: Assuming that `Old code` resides in cell `A1` of each sheet, then you can use `=INDEX(Sheet2!$A$2:$A$6,MATCH(Sheet1!B2,Sheet2!$B$2:$B$6,0))` in cell `A2` and copy down

Comment: Hi Spectral Instance, thanks for that. A quick look at index() shows me it's looking for an array in argument 1, so in this instance it's my old codes from sheet 2, which (because of the header) start in A2 of that sheet. Argument 2 is row_num, so in this formula we're asking it to lookup B2, which is the new code in sheet 2, and to look within B2:B6 which is presumably the range (in my case 26000 rows?!) and return an exact match? Is that right? I'm just a bit thrown by the double $, why for example is it not $A2:$A6?

Comment: The double `$` is the default for 'locking' a reference when using the [`F4`](https://exceljet.net/shortcuts/toggle-absolute-and-relative-references) key - the formula could be written as `=INDEX(Sheet2!A$2:A$6,MATCH(Sheet1!B2,Sheet2!B$2:B$6,0))` - if the `$` were omitted from this formula, it would no longer produce the correct results, as it would be referring to `A3:A7`/`B3:B7` in the first cell copied down, and to `A4:A8`/`B4:B8` in the second cell copied down etc. btw. 26k cells is _not_ a large range for either the `INDEX()` or `MATCH()`functions